# How to calculate average of 10 values in excel excluding max 2 and min 2 value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

[image]

How can I calculate the average of 10 values in excel excluding max 2 and min 2 values?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `B1:B12` is the range,
`=(SUM(B1:B12)-LARGE(B1:B12,2)-SMALL(B1:B12,2))/(COUNT(B1:B12)-2)`
will do.

Comment: `LARGE(B1:B12,2)` is the second largest value, not the sum of 1st and 2nd.

Comment: @Máté Juhász: Exactly. OP illustrates the question with 12 numbers
and asks a way to find an average of 10 
excluding two values, max 2 and min 2,
supposedly, second large and second small.

Comment: thanks

Its Done

=(SUM(J5:U5)-(LARGE(J5:U5,1)+LARGE(J5:U5,2)+SMALL(J5:U5,1)+SMALL(J5:U5,2)))/(COUNT(J5:U5)-4)